# css div parent border relative positioning

Tags: css, css-position

Have a parent div and child div.  Using relative positioning in the child div element to place the contents of it.  parent div element border  is  not enclosing the child div element.  Tried overflow:hidden and padding options in parent div element but it's not working.  http://jsfiddle.net/p5UMA/1/   pasted the code below

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        font-size: 100%;
        font: inherit;
        vertical-align: baseline;
}

#parid{
color:#000000;
border: 3px solid #336c2b;
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;    
}
#childcon{
background-color: #000000;
color:#ffffff;
border: 5px solid #003748;
position:relative;
left:100px;
top:100px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
     <div id="parid">
        <div id="childcon">
                child contents
        </div>
     </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: think of the value as meaning "relative to me" for the element has position "relative".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [dev.opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/36-css-static-and-relative-positioning/)

> The thing to remember about relative positioning is that it’s only the
>   generated box that is shifted. The element still remains where it was
>   in the static document flow. That’s where it “takes up space” as far
>   as other elements are concerned. This means that the shifted box may
>   end up overlapping other elements’ boxes, because they still act like
>   the relatively positioned element has remained where it should be,
>   before the positioning was applied.

Use `margin` instead

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/p5UMA/9/)

```
#childcon{
   background-color: #000000;
   color:#ffffff;
   border: 5px solid #003748;
   position:relative;
   margin-left:100px;
   margin-top:100px;
}
```

For example, increasing the child element `height` will lead to increase the `height` of parent element as well, it just shifts the child element, but the literal element `position` stays where it is...

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/p5UMA/10/)

Comment: yeah, also think of the value as meaning "relative to me" for the element has position "relative"

Answer (score 0):

This may help you out

```
#childcon{
 background-color: #000000;
 color:#ffffff;
 border: 5px solid #003748;
 margin:100px 0 0 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="parid">
        <div id="childcon">
                child contents
        </div>
         <div style="clear:both;"></div>
     </div>

#childcon{
background-color: #000000;
color:#ffffff;
border: 5px solid #003748;
position:relative;
margin:100px 0 0 100px;
```

see this link http://jsfiddle.net/bipin_kumar/p5UMA/16/